# Wake On LAN timing out when computer left off overnight

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, raspberry-pi, wake-on-lan

I have a direct ethernet connection between a Windows 10 PC and a Raspberry Pi.

I have the Pi set up as a server that I can hop onto and run a script that will run Etherwake, a command line Wake on lan program, and it works fine when I test it by turning off my computer and letting it sit for a minute, then I run the command and the computer turns on.

But when I let it sit overnight, it doesn't work anymore. Running the script does nothing.

From what I've been reading, a lot of people fix this by messing with some sort of ARP settings on their router, but there isn't a router in this situation- again, its a direct ethernet cable running between the two computers.

Comment: WoL is supported in S3 (Sleep) and S4 (Hibernate) by Windows. Additionally, your NIC (network interface card) allows it in S5 (Soft Off) where the PC is powered minimally (at the MoBo) including your NIC. However it seems your device is going into G3 (Mechanical Off : Hot) State where the NIC is not powered. Your PC is going into G3 (Hot) from S5 likely. Is it your PSU or MoBo? Check your BIOS power settings perhaps. I only know this from documentation, I'm not certain this is the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The machine that transmits the WoL magic packet onto the LAN must know the MAC address of the machine than needs to be awakened. For people waking a home machine from elsewhere, their gateway router is the machine that's forwarding the packet onto the LAN, so the router is the machine that needs the static entry in its ARP table.

In your scenario, your Raspberry Pi is the machine that needs the static entry in its ARP table.